# PHP upload script works locally, however not on remote server

Tags: php, upload, mamp, bluehost

It's strange, this script works locally (on MAMP), but not on my remote server (Bluehost). I tried adding some POST data, and that worked, however the file upload isn't working at all. Any ideas?

```
//upload file
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000) && isSet($_FILES["file"])){
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "<div class='error'>Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</div>";
}else{
    if (file_exists("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
        echo "<div class='error'>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. </div>";
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
}
}else{
if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))){
    //echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
}else{
    if(isSet($_FILES["file"]["type"]) && !isSet($message)){
        echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file type.</div>";
    }
}
}
```

Here is the upload form.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

The upload folder's permissions are set to "775".

I'd appreciate any help/ideas.

**Update**

Problem solved. It was a php.ini issue. I'm not sure where the problem was exactly. However, when I restored the default php.ini, file it worked.

Comment: But what is the folder's ownership? That is as important as the permissions mode.

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs?  Can you add some debugging output to the code and see what's happening?  "It doesn't work" isn't particularly useful information...

Comment: What do you mean by "at all" ? Any error messages? Server response code? $_FILES array dump could also help understand the problem.

Comment: Agree with David--any error messages? Your relative path is going to be in relation to the execution path of your PHP script. Are you certain that your uploads folder can be accessed by the same relative path on the server? Always safer to use absolute paths, and there are some magic variables that can help you get there.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I just double checked and the $_FILES data returns as NULL upon testing with an array dump.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a php.ini issue. I'm not sure where the problem was exactly. However, when I restored the default php.ini, file it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think problems is with the read-write-execute permission of the upoading folder in server. Make sure that the destination folder have read-write-execute(777) permissions.